# Struts2 - Session Troubles

Tags: session, struts2, javabeans

I make (thanks with some users on this portal) my application that implements SessionAware.

This is my actual code :

```
public class UserManager extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private Map<String, Object> session;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session=map;
    }

    public String checkLogin() {        
        session.put("loggedOn", true);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String checkLogout() {
        session.clear();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And i check these variables on my .jsp :

```
<s:if test="#session['loggedOn']!=true">
    DIV LOGIN
</s:if>
<s:else>
    DIV LOGOUT
</s:else>
```

An easy piece of code.

What i'd like to know is this :

1 - the bean is (as default) request scoped. So when the request is finished it will be destroyed. But i see that, when i put a variable in the Map, it still alive on the server. How is possible? Is a variable of my Bean.

2 - Who call the setSession method? I think the servlet, due to the fact I implements that interface?

3 - I would like to detach about saving object/bean on a Session Object. I'd like to use the Bean session scoped (as for any kind of MVC framework). How can I do it on struts2?

Hope you can make clear these questions :) Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your bean is a struts2 action as such it is action scoped (which is a more restrictive scope than request).  I say that action is a lesser scope because you can forward an action to another action in which case the previous action goes out of scope, request scoped objects however will stay in scope until the request is served.  When you implement SessionAware you are provided with a reference to the SessionObject you are then putting your object into the Session object who's life span is much longer than your action.  Clear your browser cache will remove the session value... you can also remove them by code be implementing SessionAware and removing the value from the map.

2 -  The session already exists.  You can get the session and add keys but even if you don't put anything in it, it will be there for use.

3 - You have a later question already for this topic see my answer there.

Comment: 1 & 2 - Ok now is more clear. The session-map reference is set to the Action Bean trought `public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) { this.session=map; }`. But WHO call this method? When i do an action (i call that Bean) i see that this function is called... How is possible? Is it the servlet?

Comment: No it is an interceptor that does it!  In your struts.xml you'll see that your package declaration has 'extends="struts-default"' so what does this mean?  Well how does your action get the values from the forms set on it?  How does your Session automatically get called?  How does the values get from your Action to your JSP? ... it's all done by Interceptors... You need to look at something important: Open the Struts2-core-x.x.x.jar (where  x.x.x is current version) and look in the default package, open struts-default.xml you will find 'package name="struts-default"',

Comment: you'll find 'interceptor-stack name="defaultStack"' which is a list of interceptors they all get invoked one after another until your action is reached and then they all go back up the stack until the request is served.  You'll not that there are other stacks to choose from but you'll see at the very bottom 'default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"' so that is why this stack in this package is used =)  Now the stacks list the interceptors by name but higher you'll see all the interceptors defined and the class they use (in the xwork jar) so you should quickly skim this and look up

Comment: each class and look over the JavaDoc... because each of these gives you some functionality that makes struts2 tick.  You are choosing to use 'struts-default' for your package of actions but you can 'extend' this stack and add your own interceptor (just think of it as a function added to the end of the chain) which will get invoked every time an action in that package is called.